# Сжатие битмап Андроид Ява

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. В приложения при нажатии на кнопу выбираем изоброжения из галереи. При каждом нажатии на кнопку выбираем одну фотку из галереи при этом максимум можно выбрать три изобржения. Все окей до того момента когда в третий раз выбираешь большое изоброжения (3000х2200) он вылитает.
сжимаю его таким способом:

```
bitmapArr[2] =   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri), 1300,   1000, false);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Приложили бы logcat, чтобы увидеть с какой ошибкой вылетает, будет больше шансов, что вам смогут помочь

Comment: Как правильно [работать с Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html).